# Semantic way to select current or active links in navigation menu

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, semantic-markup

Currently the most common way to identify the current link is adding a class to the anchor or its parent:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

This technique has a couple of drawbacks:

- Adding the class is often delegated to server languages and it means an extra work just for presentation.
- Even though there is a convention around the `active` class name, it's a [stupid selector](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/20/semantic-css-with-intelligent-selectors/) and doesn't seem to be semantically correct.

I tried the following with no success:

- I looked for something like the `:target` pseudo-class, so the selector could be: `a:current`, unfortunately it doesn't exist yet.
- I thought the `rel` attribute was a good candidate, but I couldn't find any that fit.
- Adding and attibute to the `nav` that sets the current link, but we need to add `id`s to every link, and CSS will become verbose

  ```
  <style>
  [data-active^="home"] a[id^="home"]{ color:red; }
  </style>
  <nav data-active="home-link"><ul>
      <li><a id="home-link">Home</a>
      ...
  ```

<del>Is there a different way to select current links that is semantically correct?</del>

The purpose of selecting with CSS the *current or active link* is to give the user a clue about the section or document is currently viewing. As @BoltClock pointed out the `active` class is *semantically meaningless* and the question is if there is a *semantically meaningful* way to select the link that belongs to the section or document the user is visting?

Comment: The question asks for “semantic way” but does not define the semantics (meaning) of the word “current”.

Comment: @Anonymous: Code nested in lists is tricky - you need to indent each line with 8 spaces for it to render correctly. I see you were on mobile when you edited this, that certainly didn't make it any less difficult :/ I've fixed the post.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: I think it means "this document".

Comment: @BoltClock, if “current link” means “this document link”, presumably meaning “a link to the document itself”, then it’s something that should not be there in the first place. It’s bad for usability and for accessibility, and very illogical at that.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: I agree that authors shouldn't deliberately create links pointing to the same document. But in this case, it's a site-wide navigation link, and those links almost always end up pointing back to the same page by their ubiquitous nature, which I think is forgivable.

Comment: @BoltClock, if this is indeed the question (and we have no confirmation to this so far), then it really means solving the wrong problem. What should be done is to prevent the item from becoming a link at all; e.g., in a navigation list, there should be non-link text in the place where the current page appears in the list on other pages. You can make it `<a>...</a>` without attributes and style it easily. The question how to generate such navigation lists depends on server-side technology (or authoring techniques) used.

Answer (score 4):

> I looked for something like the `:target` pseudo-class, so the selector could be: `a:current`, unfortunately it doesn't exist yet.

Indeed, no such selector exists yet, so what you have is already your best bet. The following pseudo-classes *sound* like they might be what you're looking for, but they mean different things:

- `:active` matches an element that is being designated by the cursor; usually this means an element that is being clicked.
- `:target` matches an element whose ID matches the URL hash fragment, which means it only works for hash fragments and not the URL path itself.
- [`:current` appears in Selectors 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-current-pseudo), but it means something quite different entirely: it matches the chronologically current element. Since HTML itself doesn't have a concept of a timeline, `:current` will match nothing (although I can imagine captioning or AT tools making full use of it in an HTML document).

That said, there *is* in fact a pseudo-class being proposed in Selectors 4 that targets the current document, only it's called [`:local-link`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-local-link-pseudo):

```
a:local-link { color: red; }
```

Of course, no implementations actually exist yet, so you're stuck with using a class name for the foreseeable future.

As helion3 has pointed out, the reason class names are used is because they're the easiest solution that exists today, and is tried, tested and true tradition dating back *decades*. Keep in mind that even HTML does not have "current-document" semantics beyond URL fragments, so you're really not going to be able to go any further than a class name or a custom data attribute with a hardcoded value.

I don't disagree with that article you've linked to either, but given there *isn't* in fact a "semantically correct" approach to this since no pseudo-class exists with the proper semantics, again you're basically stuck with this. If it makes you feel better, note that class names aren't really semantically incorrect in this case, rather they are semantically *meaningless*, i.e. they have no influence whatsoever on the meaning of the context they are in, or the document as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

*current* is a concept that CSS doesn't have because CSS isn't involved with route handling. We use the active/current/at class names because it's the easiest way.

Javascript can easily set/remove classes based on routing, as can server-side languages.

Also, navigation structures are different and in your example, it's not the anchor that's active, but the `li`. That should be left to developers to establish based on the needs of the styles.

Comment: I agree we need some help from javascript or server-side languages because route handling is not the CSS scope, but we still lack a _semantically meaninful_ atribute to mark this link, that's why `active` class is widespread used.

Comment: I concur. *active* actually means something to css, hence the `:active` psuedoclass. I've always preferred using `class="at"`, it's short and pretty hard to misunderstand.

Comment: I like the `at` class, it can be even shorter: `@`, and the css selector  `.\@`.  The problem is that clases are arbitrary defined by the developer, that's why using an standard attribute makes the markup more portable.