# css selector for link you are at

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector that will work when you are on a link. For example if I am on the homepage of my website and it is called default.aspx and there is a link on the page to default.aspx I would like it to reformat the default.aspx link. I have not seen a CSS selector for this. I do not even know if it is possible but if it is I hope someone will know. If there is a way to do it without css selectors please tell me about that also.

Comment: Yes, it is. Use css `:target`.

Comment: `:target` doesn't select the links pointing to the current page, it selects the element indicated in the hash value of the URL (eg: the element with the same id as the hash)

Comment: Since you are using asp, you could just add a class to the link of the current page (ie .active) server-side. That is how I normally do it. If your not building a singe page application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591400/semantic-way-to-select-current-or-active-links-in-navigation-menu (which is closed... go figure)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semantic way to select current or active links in navigation menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591400/semantic-way-to-select-current-or-active-links-in-navigation-menu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a specific CSS selector for the same/current page. But there are other options to select a link pointing to a specific page/anchor (although probably you'd be looking for the [`^=` attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)). You could do something like:

- `a[href="default.aspx"]` (considering that you are at default.aspx).

  This will select all the links (`a` tags) which **href value is exactly default.aspx**. That includes only links of the type: `<a href="default.aspx">...</a>`

  - Pros: Specific.
  - Cons: Really specific; It will only select the anchors with that exact text in the href, and not things like default.aspx#something.
- `a[href^="default.aspx"]` (considering that you are at default.aspx).

  This will select all the links which **href value starts with default.aspx**. That includes links of the types: `<a href="default.aspx">...</a>`, `<a href="default.aspx?somekey=somevalue">...</a>`, `<a href="default.aspx#something">...</a>`, etc.

  - Pros: It covers multiple cases.
  - Cons: It excludes multiple cases too (for example, it won't select links of the type http://mysite/default.aspx even when they are the type that you want).
- `a[href*="default.aspx"]` (considering that you are at default.aspx)

  This will select all the links which **href contains the string default.aspx** (it doesn't matter in which position). That includes links like `<a href="default.aspx">...</a>`, `<a href="http://mysite/default.aspx">...</a>`, `<a href="https://mysite/default.aspx?key=value">...</a>`, etc.

  - Pros: It is the most generic that you can use, will select everything containing the page name.
  - Cons: It is too generic and may select links that you don't want (eg: `<a href="page2.aspx?source=default.aspx">...</a>` will be selected too even when it's not pointing to the same page where the link is).
- `a[href^="#"]`

  This will select the links pointing to an anchor within the page (the **href value starts with #**). As the anchor is within the same page, you don't need to specify the file name. That includes links like this: `<a href="#something">...</a>`.

  - Pros: It only selects links to anchors within the page.
  - Cons: It only selects links to anchors within the page.

---

Taking into account how specific the first selector is, and how general the third selector is, I would go with a combination of the second and fourth selectors:

```
a[href^="default.aspx"], 
a[href^="#"] {
    // styles to highlight links to self
}
```

And still this solution would be really specific for default.aspx (links to default.aspx from other pages would be highlighted too). One alternative would be to use a class specific for each page in the selector. For example, if default.aspx has the class `.default`, and page1 has the class `.page1`, etc:

```
.default a[href^="default.aspx"], 
.page1 a[href=^="page1.aspx"],
a[href^="#"] {
    // styles to highlight links to self
}
```